# Errors with SLF4J => Windows 7 64bits & jre, jdk 7

Tags: java, slf4j

I try to convert my thrift files to Parquet files with a java converter.

I have errors :

```
14/06/13 11:51:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I don't know why, I'm on windows 7 64bits with intellij 13.1.2 and I use JRE&JDK 7 64bits.

My pom.xml is containing :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Are you sure it's related to Hadoop ?

Comment: The first error "Unable to load native-hadoop library" ... So, of course.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. It's probably caused by the fact you're using a compiled jar without `-Dnative=windows` (which is normal, since it comes from maven). However, it is not causing the second message `Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".`

Comment: You are right, I've deleted Hadoop issue of my post.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two different warnings:

The warning: "native-hadoop library for your platform..." means you don't have the 64-bit dll with hadoop optimisations on your system path.

The warning: "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"" means it does not find any SLF4J implementation on the classpath. That's weird since slf4j-simple should contain that class. Maybe try to use slf4j-over-log4j instead of slf4j-simple?

Both cases are just warnings. The missing hadoop dll means you don't get native optimalizations, but only pure java code, which might be a little slower.

The missing SLF4j implementation means you don't get any logging from hadoop, which might be more inconvenient.